# Editable Text in Raphaël

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Is there a way to make a svg text editable in Raphaël JS as described in the SVG 1.2 Specifications (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20040226/#text-edit)?

```
textelement.attr("editable", "true");
```

does not add the *editable* attribute to the textelement as I had hoped.

If there is no way I guess I will have to work with hovering html textelements…

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: All the browsers Raphaël is supporting, but I guess there is no solution to that so I am going to replace all svg text elements by html inputs

Comment: You could create an floating edit box when someone clicks on the text and then replace the text with the newly input.  Or ask Dmitry to implement it:-)

Comment: This question is about text boxes.  Prophets and mountains were never mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael isn't a 100% SVG implementation.  It only uses SVG & VML as a base.  Therefore somethings may work, while others don't work quite as you expect and somethings don't work at all.

Comment: I just want to make sure there is no possibility as changing all my svg text elements to html elements at this point of the project would be quite time consuming

Answer (score 3):

The specification you link to is a working draft (a work in progress, subject to change). However, the [SVG Tiny 1.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/) does have almost the [same thing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#text-edit), and it is a w3c Recommendation. Of course that doesn't magically make every implementation do what it says, but it's at least stable.

If you're looking for an implementation that does support ['editable'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#text-edit) on svg text elements, then [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) is one example.

Comment: I am looking for a solution based an Raphaël as all my text elements are already composed that way

Comment: You could use `textelement.node.setAttribute("editable", "simple")` assuming textelement is a raphaël Element object. But that only gets you so far, so yes, in general you're going to have to go for html elements if you want it to work crossbrowser.